# Additive Persistence Algorithm Java

Tags: java

I need some guidance as I am *very* new to coding.

I am writing a program that finds the [additive persistence of a number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_a_number), showing each sum of the way.

Here is some clarification if you do not know what additive persistence is:

Additive persistence is a property of the sum of the digits of an integer. The sum of the digits is found, and then the summation of digits is performed on the sum, repeating until a single integer digit is reached. The number of such cycles is that integer's additive persistence. Consider the following example:

1. The beginning integer is 1234
2. Sum its digits 1+2+3+4 = 10
3. The integer is now 10
4. The sum of its digits is 1 + 0 = 1
5. The integer is 1. When the value reaches a single digit, we are finished. This final integer is the additive root.

---

I don't know whether it's my syntax or whatever, but I really thought I solved the algorithm on my own. However, no output comes up when I put in a number. Any assistance or pointers would be much appreciated. I am so lost.

---

```
package persistence;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Persistence {

   public static void main(String [ ] args) {       

        int n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\nEnter an Integer -- Cannot be negative"));

        if (n < 10) {

            int ap = 0;
            int ar;

            ap += 1;
            ar = 1 + ( (n - 1) % 9 );

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Additive Persistence of " + n + " is " + ap + " and the Digital Root is " + ar);
        } 

        int num1 = n;
        int num2 = 0;
        int num3 = 0;
        int result = 0;

            if (n >= 10) {

                while (num3 > 0) {

                num2 = num1 % 10;
                result = result + num2;
                num3 = num1 / 10;
                num1 = num3;

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sum:" + result);
              }
                    }
       }
       }
```

---

Why doesn't the code show any result ?

Comment: Your while loop, `while (num3 > 0)` — `num3` starts at zero, so the loop is never entered.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have gotten rid of num3.  while (num1 > 0) {
                
                num2 = num1 % 10;
                result = result + num2;
                num1 = num1 / 10;
                count++;

Answer (score 3):

Instead of converting the string to an integer right away, you could convert each char in the string to an int and sum them up. If the resulting value is not less than 10, do it again. Here's a recursive example:

```
private int additivePersistence(String num)
{
    if(num.length() == 1) //If the number is a single digit, we're done
        return Integer.parseInt(num);

    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++)
        sum += (num.charAt(i) - '0'); //Gets integer value of char, adds it to sum

    return additivePersistence(Integer.toString(sum));
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just writing code, you could include try-catch block. Your code currently doesn't handle Exceptions. If user enters string character instead of a number, it will throw `NumberFormatException`. So, you could use catch block with :

```
    try {  
//your code above   
} catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
{  
System.out.println("Number entered is not numeric."+ nfe.getMessage());  
                    }
```

Also, consider using:

```
System.exit(0); after if statement so that program stops after calculation.
```